# Python: shouldn't open(False, "rb") raise an exception?

Tags: python, pickle

I've just observed that the following little Python 3.8 program

```
import pickle

with open(False, "rb") as file:
    print("Inside context block")
    o = pickle.load(file)
print("Out of the context block")
```

outputs `Inside context block` and freezes at `pickle.load`.

1. Shouldn't `open` fail and raise an exception in this case?
2. Shouldn't `pickle.load` fail and raise an exception in this case?

Comment: `False` is equivalent to 0 in Python.

Comment: According to [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open), `open`'s first positional argument *"is a path-like object giving the pathname (absolute or relative to the current working directory) of the file to be opened or **an integer file descriptor** of the file to be wrapped"* (emphasis mine). Since `False` is equal to the integer `0`, the latter seems to apply.